# Can I use Frontend Library in Serverside

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, face-detection

I'm using Toonify, which is an API to cartoonize pictures.
However, since this is not free, it costs each time I call, even if they cannot detect a face in the picture.

So before I call the API, I want to use another library to detect face, then if there is, I want to call the Toonify API.

I've tried several libraries,

- [face-api.js](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js)
  (too good quality. It detect faces that Toonify cannot detect)
- [clmtrackr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clmtrackr)
- [facedetector](https://github.com/riversun/facedetector)

I think using clmtrackr is the best way to use, because it cannot detect faces that Toonify also cannot detect.

But when I install clmtrackr in backend, node.js server, and run it returns error because the "window" is not defined.

That I figured out that it's for browser library. But I need to use it.

Is there any way I can use browser-library like clmtrackr or facedetector in Node.js server?